# Get form data in HTTP call using angular

Tags: angular, typescript, ionic-framework, ionic2, angular2-routing

```
This is how the authentication is supposed to be.
```

POST https://DomainName/api/v1/authentication?username={username}&password={password}..
this is the typescript authentication call code

```
authenticate(url, payload){
let username: string = 'admin';
let password: string = 'password';
let headers: Headers = new Headers();
  headers.append("Authorization", "Basic " + btoa(username + ":" + password)); 
  headers.append("Content-Type", "application/json");
  headers.append("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
return this.http.post(server + url + addon, payload, { headers:headers });
```

this is the code for the form data

```
    // Getting data info from signing form
loginForm = new FormGroup({
username: new FormControl(null, ([Validators.required, Validators.minLength(5)])),
password: new FormControl(null, ([Validators.required, Validators.minLength(5)])),
})
```

the user data

```
// user data 
loginData={
username:'',
    password:'',
}

buildLoginData(){
    this.loginData.password = this.loginForm.controls['password'].value;
this.loginData.username = this.loginForm.controls['username'].value;
}
```

the sign in function

```
    signin(){
    this.loading =this.loadingCtrl.create({
  content:"Verifying Credentials ..."
});
this.loading.present();
    this.buildLoginData();
    console.log(this.loginData);
  this.http.store('authentication', this.loginData).subscribe((response)=>{
            // console.log(response);
            // console.log("*******************************************");
            // console.log(response['username']);
            localStorage.setItem('office_ID',response['officeId']);
            localStorage.setItem('user_ID', response['userId']);
            localStorage.setItem('username', response['username']);
            this.loading.dismissAll();
            this.navCtrl.push(HomePage);
  },error=>{
            this.loading.dismissAll();
                if(error.status === 401){
                    this.toastr.messenger('Wrong Username or Password');
                }else
    this.toastr.messenger('Login Failed!');
            console.log(JSON.stringify(error));
            alert("Error : " + error );
});    
}
```

Response log data

```
{"_body":"{\"developerMessage\":\"Invalid authentication details were 
passed in api request.\",\"httpStatusCode\":\"401\",\"defaultUserMessage 
\":\"Unauthenticated. Please login.\",\"userMessageGlobalisationCode
\":\"error.msg.not.authenticated\",\"errors
\":[]}","status":401,"ok":false,"statusText":"Unauthorized","headers":
{"Content-Type":["application/json"]},"type":2,"url":"https//x.x.x.x:xxxx            
/xxxxxxxxx/api/v1/authentication?tenantIdentifier=default"}
```

the error

```
 "Unauthorized" and this is because the form values are not being sent to                                                                                     
  the api as headers.
```

Any help is much Appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: so whats the error??

Comment: @UnluckyAj the error response is "Unauthorized" and this is because the form values are not being sent to the api as headers.

Comment: @JONATHANOKINE: Please add . the error to your question to make it clear for the user to help. If not, User will have to search the error in the your comment and they might oversee it.

Comment: @k.vincent i have added it. thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Does your `this.http.store(url,data)` 
add the url Parameters behind the scene? 
 `authentication?username={username}&password={password}..`
 if not the quick way is to do it yourself
`` const url =`authenticationusername=${this.loginData.username}&password=${this.loginData.password}` ``

 then your can do 
`this.http.store(url,this.loginData)` 
 
Or you can look at URL Parameters https://angular.io/guide/http#url-parameters

Comment: username=${this.loginData.username}&password=${this.loginData.password} signin.ts:70:6
{"_body":"{\"developerMessage\":\"Invalid authentication details were passed in api request.\",\"httpStatusCode\":\"401\",\"defaultUserMessage\":\"Unauthenticated. Please login.\",\"userMessageGlobalisationCode\":\"error.msg.not.authenticated\",\"errors\":[]}","status":401,"ok":false,"statusText":"Unauthorized","headers":{"Content-Type":["application/json"]},"type":2,"url":"https://x.x.x.x:xxx/xxxxxxx/api/v1/authentication?tenantIdentifier=default"}

Comment: sorry, change the single quote ' to `